# Finding a grammar or a pushdown automaton that recognizes { a^i b^j b^i a^j | i,j >= 0 }

Tags: context-free-grammar, automata, pushdown-automaton, automaton

I am trying to find either a grammar or a pushdown automaton that recognizes the following language:

{ a<sup>i</sup> b<sup>j</sup> b<sup>i</sup> a<sup>j</sup> | i,j >= 0 }

Of all the examples that I have seen, I cannot wrap my head around this one!

I first tried using a grammar for it as I think this may be easier recursively, and then a pushdown automaton, with no luck. I don't know what to do with the b<sup>j</sup> in-between a<sup>i</sup> and b<sup>i</sup>.

Comment: I don't think this is context free. I'm a bit rusty, so I don't see it instantly. I'd try to prove this using the [Pumping lemma for CFLs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_context-free_languages).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as `i + j = j + i`, `bibj = bjbi`. In other words, two b's are indistinguishable from each other.

Perhaps you will find it easier to see the grammar for `{ aibibjaj | i,j ≥ 0 }`